# Count days in Jekyll

Tags: count, jekyll, liquid

I have a a Jekyll website and I would like to create a day counter, starting from 1 and then every day it should add +1 to the counter.

So today it would say:

> Day 1

Tomorrow it should say

> Day 2

The day after:

> Day 3

is that possible to do in jekyll?

Comment: How many days would you like it to do this? You have access to `{{ 'now' | date: '%u' }}` Which time zone will you be using?

Comment: 30 days, I will use CST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to calculate the difference between two dates. There is some discussion about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615552/1645925

My favourite answer states:

```
{% assign today = site.time | date: '%s' %}
{% assign start = '20-01-2014 04:00:00' | date: '%s' %}
{% assign secondsSince = today | minus: start %}
{% assign hoursSince = secondsSince | divided_by: 60 | divided_by: 60     %}
{% assign daysSince = hoursSince | divided_by: 24  %}

Hours: {{hoursSince}}
Days: {{daysSince}}
```

I believe `site.time` refers to the server time that your site is hosted on but you can use `'now'` to use the users time.

Comment: I think `site.time` returns the time when your site was built, and the value won't change over time.

Comment: replace your hard coded date with post.date and this is a great way to show your posts were posted 'x days ago'.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a web page that tells you: today is day number 16 of the month.

Because Jekyll is a static site generator, all logic will only be executed during generation of the site. When you do not update/rebuild your website (daily), the counter does not increment. I think using javascript is the only solution for this problem.

Given my assumption, the answer is: No, Jekyll does not do this. You should use javascript for this.